# Setting preference summary

Tags: java, design-patterns, android

I'm taking and Android course and I would like to refactor the code for one of the exercises. The complete solution done by tutors is [here](https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Sunshine/blob/student/S06.03-Solution-PolishingPreferences/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/SettingsFragment.java).

When I was doing this exercise by myself I was annoyed by those `ifs` with `instanceofs` and by the fact that class containing too much logic.

Also, due to the fact this code used to be common at most apps, I think it should be moved to a different class.

This code set the summary of each preference in a preference screen (see the image below). To illustrate that, here is a picture from my phone running other simply preference screen.

I have created a simply factory class (`SummaryResolverFactory`) an interface (SummaryResolver) and a bunch of implementation for each type of Android preference type (`ListPreferenceSummaryResolver`, .

I couldn't eliminate the "`instanceof ifs`" it will be doing only once within factory class.

```
public interface SummarySetter {
    void setSummary(Object value);
}

public final class SummarySetterFactory {

    public static SummarySetter createFrom(Preference preference) {
        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            return new ListPreferenceSummarySetter((ListPreference) preference);
        } else if (preference instanceof CheckBoxPreference) {
            return new CheckboxSummarySetter((CheckBoxPreference) preference);
        } else if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
            return new EditTextSummarySetter((EditTextPreference) preference);
        } else if (preference instanceof SwitchPreferenceCompat) {
            return new EmptySummarySetter();
        }
        return new EmptySummarySetter();
    }

    private static class EmptySummarySetter implements SummarySetter {
        @Override
        public void setSummary(Object value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented yet");
        }
    }

}

public class CheckboxSummarySetter extends AbstractSummarySetter<CheckBoxPreference> {
    public CheckboxSummarySetter(CheckBoxPreference preference) {
        super(preference);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSummary(Object value) {

        /* does nothing. CheckboxSummary is setted automatically by its status and attribtes
        summaryOn and summaryOf from CheckBoxPreference;*/
    }
}




public class ListPreferenceSummarySetter extends AbstractSummarySetter<ListPreference> {
    private static final String TAG = "ListPreferenceSummarySe";

    public ListPreferenceSummarySetter(ListPreference preference) {
        super(preference);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSummary(Object value) {
        int index = preference.findIndexOfValue((String) value);
        if (index < 0) {
            return;
        }

        CharSequence summary = preference.getEntries()[index];
        preference.setSummary(summary);
    }
}

public class EditTextSummarySetter extends AbstractSummarySetter<EditTextPreference> {

    public EditTextSummarySetter(EditTextPreference preference) {
        super(preference);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSummary(Object value) {
        preference.setSummary((CharSequence) value);
    }
}
public class CheckboxSummarySetter extends AbstractSummarySetter<CheckBoxPreference> {
    public CheckboxSummarySetter(CheckBoxPreference preference) {
        super(preference);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSummary(Object value, Object defaultValue) {

        /* does nothing. CheckboxSummary is setted automatically by its status and attribtes
        summaryOn and summaryOf from CheckBoxPreference;*/
    }
}



public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    private static final String TAG = "SetttingsFragment";


    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefsunshine);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreatePreferences: ");
        PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = preferenceScreen.getSharedPreferences();
        int preferenceCount = preferenceScreen.getPreferenceCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < preferenceCount; i++) {
            Preference preference = preferenceScreen.getPreference(i);
            setSummary(sharedPreferences, preference);
        }

    }

    private void setSummary(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, Preference preference) {
        SummarySetter summarySetter = SummarySetterFactory.createFrom(preference);
        String value = sharedPreferences.getString(preference.getKey(), "");
        Log.d(TAG, "setSummary: "+value);
        summarySetter.setSummary(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSharedPreferenceChanged: "+key);
        Preference preference = findPreference(key);
        if (preference == null) {
            return;
        }

        setSummary(sharedPreferences, preference);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
}
```

ps. 
ListPreference, CheckBoxPreference, PreferenceFragmentCompat and other misses classes are Android SDK stuff.

[image]

Please, review my code about any aspects you think is relevant.

One question about performance: these object creation whenever user change a property is a risk to performance? I like this way of doing things (creating objects) I think in java this is not so problematic anymore. In Android maybe.

thanks in advance